# PrepareForSegue between UIView and ViewController using Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UIView in a view controller which displays an image. This UIView is associated to classX, while the view controller it is in is associated to classY.
My question is, how can I use prepareForSegue in the case? I want to send data from my viewController class to the UIView class to display an image depending on the value it receives respectively.

I have it this way because in classX I need to inherit the UIView class to display the pictures, while in classY I need to inherit the UIViewController because i have functions that need it there; from my knowledge, I cannot inherit both together.

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an IBOutlet for the image view in your view controller so you can access it.

The view controller or any code in prepareForSegue can now access the image view and set its contents using whatever methods your image class provides.